# Choice of ML algorithm for problem

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

Working on a school project where we have to match some users based on common interests. Assuming I have a list of inputs like this:

- Name Interest**1** Interest**2** Interest**3** Interest**4** Interest**5**
- Name Interest**4** Interest**6** Interest**7** Interest**8** Interest**9**
- Name Interest**1** Interest**2** Interest**4** Interest**3** Interest**5**
- Name Interest**7** Interest**8** Interest**9** Interest**11** Interest**12**

And another user comes

- Name Interest**4** Interest**6** Interest**13** Interest**12** Interest**7**

Closest match for him would be user 2. If I want to take a ML approach in solving this what algorithm would fit this kind of problem?

Comment: Looks like a classic recommender problem, right? ALS to create user embeddings and then find nearest neighbors according to cosine similarity?

Comment: @SeanOwen thank you for the tip with cosine; looked into that and it's probably what we're gonna use! What exactly is ALS for user embeddings? Can you give a bit more details or atleast what does ALS stand for? Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an example of Recommendation based system. 
You can build a `Popularity based recommendation system` in this scenario. This type of algorithm works with trend, it basically uses the items which are in trend right now.

Else you can go for `Collaborative recommendation system` or `Content based recommendation system`

Answer (score 0):

Breaking my comment out into an answer:

This is a classic recommender problem. Given users' interactions with items, predict what other interactions are likely but unobserved. The usual algorithm for this is alternating least squares. See https://datasciencemadesimpler.wordpress.com/tag/alternating-least-squares/ for example. The details don't matter much; it's implemented in many packages like Spark (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/ml-collaborative-filtering.html).

You get recommendations (new items for users) out of it, and if that's what you want you're done. But, you also get from this model a set of user and item vectors, which can be viewed as embeddings of users and items into a latent factor space.

All this means is that it's valid to define 'similar' users and items as those that have a large cosine similarity. The simplistic way to find similar users is just the brute force one: for a given user, find cosine similarity with all users and take the top ones.

There are faster approximate ways to do it, like a simple locality-sensitive hash (LSH) of the vectors into buckets, from which you can reduce the search for similar users to the users in the same bucket as the target user.